# Validation alert using select2.js

Tags: select2-rails

I am using selec2.js. While entering values in drop down i am validating input text for special characters. After validating, i am returning true of false from validation function. If not valid i want to show error 'Special character not allowed' below input box.

```
       $jQ("selectDropDown").on("select2-selecting", function(e) {
        isValid =validateValueOnAdd(e.val, dataTypeId);
        if(!isvalid){
         {formatNoMatches:"not valid"};
            return false;
        }
```

Can someone help???